Interpreting Rate of Change of Bullet Volume with Relation to Height
The question enunciates as follows: find the equation between the rate of change of the volume of the solid of revolution generated by the graph $y = –x^2$ and the rate of change of it's height $h$ (measured longitudinally downwards along the $y$ axis) with respect to time. An image is provided the easier to visualize the problem (it doesn't contain information that you cannot already extract from the preceding enunciation):

What ofcourse quickly strikes my mind is to find first a relation between the Volume and the height then, to be able to take the derivative of both sides and hence find the relation between their rates of change after. Hence the volume of the given solid of revolution should be easily seen to be: $\int_{–h}^{0} \pi x^2 dy = \int_{–h}^{0} – \pi y dy = – \pi [\frac{y^2}{2}]_{–h}^0 = \frac{\pi h^2}{2}$
Hence $V = \frac{\pi h^2}{2}$, and differentiating both sides with respect to an independent constant to represent time $t$ we get $\frac{dV}{dt} = \frac{\pi}{2}2h \frac{dh}{dt} = \pi h \frac{dh}{dt}$.
What I cannot do is interpret what this means. How come the rate of change of the Volume also depends on $h$ itself, morover, what does that even mean? I cannot seem to wrap my head around the statement since $h$ itself is a varying quantity. Shouldn't it be able to wholly depend on $\frac{dh}{dt}$? Thank you in advance.

"Shouldn't it be able to wholly depend on $\frac{dh}{dt}$?" Can you explain why you think this? You are saying that if we increase $h$ at a constant rate (constant value of $\frac{dh}{dt}$), the rate of change of volume, which depends only on $\frac{dh}{dt}$, must also be constant. So bascially the rate of change of any function is always a constant. Do you really believe this?


Shouldn't it be able to wholly depend on $\frac{d h}{d t}$?

No. You showed it yourself: even if $\frac{d h}{d t}$ is constant, the rate at which the volume of your solid grows still depends on how big it is (i.e., what $h$ is) at any particular time. The larger $h$ is, the faster volume is added, even when $h$ grows in a time-independent fashion.
There is an intuitive (if somewhat informal) way to arrive at your answer. You can imagine a very small elapsed time $\delta t$ when the height of the solid is $h (t)$. To linear order in time, the solid grows by a cylinder whose base has radius $\sqrt{h}$ and whose height is $\frac{d h}{d t} \delta t$. The volume of this cylinder is $\delta V = \pi (\sqrt{h})^2 \left( \frac{d h}{d t} \delta t \right) = \pi h \frac{d h}{d t} \delta t$. The rate of volume growth is then $\frac{d V}{d t} = \pi h \frac{d h}{d t}$, just as you calculated.
